# Techniques to prove rather unobvious arguments

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to prove this argument but I can't seem to find a way to prove it.

$a \to b$

$b \lor c$

$(c \land \sim a) \to (d \land \sim a)$

$\sim b$

$\therefore d$

**EDIT:** Attached below is the rules we are allowed to use. [Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3J9l.png)

Comment: What are you allowed to use? What have you tried and where are you stuck? (Edit the question instead of comment to add these info)

Comment: We are allowed to use any rules of replacement and inference. 

I can't simplify/manipulate the third premise.

Comment: $x \to (y \land z)$ is the same thing as $(x \to y) \land (x \to z)$

Comment: Have you tried figuring out if the antecedent of the third premise is true or not?

Comment: There is an edit button below the question, can you see it? It is in gray text so might be difficult to notice. Please do not use comments to add to your question, comments are meant to be temporary and may get cleared.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: the fourth premise implies the third's antecedent using the first two premises.

Comment: If $a$ implies $b$, but $b$ is false, what does that tell you about $a$? If $b$ or $c$ is true, but $b$ is false, what does that tell you about $c$?

Comment: You cannot solve this with those "[rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3J9l.png) you are allowed to use".  These are logical equivalences.  They do not contain rules of logical inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ $\overline{b}\to c$ (Given Premise).

$2)$ $\overline{b}$ (premise)

$3)$ $c$ (Modus ponens of 1,2)

$4)$ $\overline{b} \to \overline{a}$ (premise)

$5)$ $\overline{a}$ (Modus ponens of 2 ,4)

$6)$ $c$ $\wedge$ $\overline{a}$ (Conjunction of 3 ,5)

$7)$ $(c$ $\wedge$ $\overline{a})$ $\implies$ $(d$ $\wedge$ $\overline{a})$ (premise)

$8)$ $d$ $\wedge$ $\overline{a}$ (Modus ponens of 6,7)

$9)$ $d$ (From 8).